# Stripe webhook host with node.js deployment

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Is it possible to host stripe webhook with node.js deploy.

I've setup my stripe webhook  with stripe checkout and It's ran successfully in localhost using stripe cli.

But I'm tried to take webhooks live.

```
const express = require("express");
const Stripe = require("stripe");
const { Order } = require("../models/Order");

require("dotenv").config();

const stripe = Stripe(`${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET}`);

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {

  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    metadata: {
      userId: req.body.userId,
      cart: JSON.stringify(req.body.products),
    },
  });

  const line_items = req.body.products.map((item) => {
    return {
      price_data: {
        currency: "usd",
        product_data: {
          name: item.title,
          description: item.description,
          metadata: {
            id: item.id,
          },
        },
        unit_amount: item.price * 100,
      },
      quantity: item.quantity,
    };
  });

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["BD", "US", "CA"],
    },
    shipping_options: [
      {
        shipping_rate_data: {
          type: "fixed_amount",
          fixed_amount: {
            amount: 0,
            currency: "usd",
          },
          display_name: "Free shipping",
          // Delivers between 5-7 business days
          delivery_estimate: {
            minimum: {
              unit: "business_day",
              value: 5,
            },
            maximum: {
              unit: "business_day",
              value: 7,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        shipping_rate_data: {
          type: "fixed_amount",
          fixed_amount: {
            amount: 1500,
            currency: "usd",
          },
          display_name: "Next day air",
          // Delivers in exactly 1 business day
          delivery_estimate: {
            minimum: {
              unit: "business_day",
              value: 1,
            },
            maximum: {
              unit: "business_day",
              value: 1,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    line_items,
    mode: "payment",
    customer: customer.id,
    success_url: `https://nobab-3b3c4.web.app/checkout-success`,
    cancel_url: `https://nobab-3b3c4.web.app/`,
  });

  // res.redirect(303, session.url);
  res.send({ url: session.url });
});

// Create order function

const createOrder = async (customer, data) => {
  const Items = JSON.parse(customer.metadata.cart);

  const products = Items.map((item) => {
    return {
      productId: item.id,
      quantity: item.quantity,
    };
  });

  const newOrder = new Order({
    userId: customer.metadata.userId,
    customerId: data.customer,
    paymentIntentId: data.payment_intent,
    products,
    subtotal: data.amount_subtotal,
    total: data.amount_total,
    shipping: data.customer_details,
    payment_status: data.payment_status,
  });

  try {
    const savedOrder = await newOrder.save();
    console.log("Processed Order:", savedOrder);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

// Stripe webhoook

router.post(
  "/webhook",
  express.json({ type: "application/json" }),
  async (req, res) => {
    let data;
    let eventType;
    // Check if webhook signing is configured.
    // let webhookSecret = `${process.env.STRIPE_WEB_HOOK}`;
    let webhookSecret;

    if (webhookSecret) {
      // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
      let event;
      let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
          req.body,
          signature,
          webhookSecret
        );

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed:  ${err}`);
        return res.sendStatus(400);
      }
      // Extract the object from the event.
      data = event.data.object;
      eventType = event.type;
    } else {
      // Webhook signing is recommended, but if the secret is not configured in `config.js`,
      // retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
      data = req.body.data.object;
      eventType = req.body.type;
    }

    // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if (eventType === "checkout.session.completed") {
      stripe.customers
        .retrieve(data.customer)
        .then(async (customer) => {
          try {
            // CREATE ORDER
            createOrder(customer, data);
            console.log("Ordered");
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Order created', data: data })
            res.status(200).send("Order created")
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(typeof createOrder);
            console.log(err);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
    }

    res.status(200).end();
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

This code working fine and store user order in mongodb database, but i need to run this after my server deployment.

Thanks everyone

for help me

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible to host webhook with Node: [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart?lang=node). It's a separated logic with your Checkout Creation endpoint, and you will need to [test the webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test) properly.

Comment: I add my endpoint url inside my stripe dashboard and also add checkout session.completed and payment.intent succeeded. both event type are called successfully and also got payment status but user data could not saved to mongodb

Comment: This `createOrder(customer, data)` seems to be async. Can you try adding `await` just to make sure that it completed successfully before continuing?